# AttributeError for Exception code

Tags: django, exception

I have this function which contains try and except. I'm having a problem in getting the code of exception.

I wrote the code like this first:

```
def _runQuery(self, query, request=None)
    try:
        //request codes here
    except Exception, e:
        messages.error(
            request,
            'Error connecting to OFX server. URL: {0} ERROR: {1} {2}'.format(
                self.account.bank.ofx_url, e.code, e.msg))
        return ''
```

My exception always give me an AttributeError that e object has no attribute 'code'. So I thought that sometimes Exception has no code render or it is null. I rewrite my codes again and this is the latest.

```
    except Exception, e:
        code = ""
        if e.code:
            code = e.code
        messages.error(
            request,
            'Error connecting to OFX server. URL: {0} ERROR: {1} {2}'.format(
                self.account.bank.ofx_url, code, e.msg))
```

Now it gives me different error - AttributeError: 'SSLError' object has no attribute 'code'

How to fix this? And get the code without this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
except Exception, e:
    code = ""
    if hasattr(e, 'code'):
        code = e.code
    messages.error(
        request,
        'Error connecting to OFX server. URL: {0} ERROR: {1} {2}'.format(
            self.account.bank.ofx_url, code, e.msg))
```

Instead of trying to access the code attribute on your exception when you check to see if it exists, you can use `hasattr()` which will return False instead of throwing another exception.

Answer (score -1):

Look at [hasattr and getattr](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#hasattr) functions:

```
messages.error(
        request,
        'Error connecting to OFX server. URL: {0} ERROR: {1} {2}'.format(
            self.account.bank.ofx_url, getattr(e, 'code', ''), e.msg))
```